# Effect size estimator and estimate

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, estimators

Effect size estimator and estimate

We wish, from the results of a study by comparison of groups carried out on samples of a population (such as student scores), to estimate the effect size at the level of this population (or also the size of real effect). Some authors will thus calculate Cohen's d, to which they associate a variance. Thus Borenstein (Introduction to meta-analysis, 2009), p.27 writes:
*"we use the symbol δ (delta) to denote the effect size parameter and d for the sample estimate of that parameter. The variance of d is given …."*
In my opinion, one can only calculate the variance of an estimator (random variable), and therefore to speak of the variance of d (which is an estimate and therefore a real number) is a misnomer. In none of the texts I have consulted have I found a definition of an effect size estimator.
I would like to clarify all of this, and that is why I need your help. Could you indicate to me one or more documents which would give the definitions of the effect size of a population, the estimator of this effect size and its estimate in the case of continuous data (for example using Cohen's d or Hedges' g)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm don't think I understand your question. A population parameter is a fixed value. As such, it doesn't have a variance. Only the sample estimate has a variance, such as a sample mean of a given sample size (i.e., the standard error of the mean). The distribution of observations in the population have a variance but the population mean itself does not. Now, under a meta-analysis random effects model we do assume that there is a distribution of population means.  There are several sample based estimators of that value.

Comment: For estimators of the variance of effect size parameters see: Viechtbauer, W. (2005). Bias and efficiency of meta-analytic variance estimators in the random-effects model. Journal of Educational and Behavioral Statistics, 30(3), 261-293.

Comment: In my opinion, an estimate has no variance. There is actually a step missing, which is to define the estimator (a random variable), because an estimate which is a number has no variance. For the sampling means, there is indeed a parameter (μ), an estimator (M (n)) and an estimate (m). What I'm missing is the definition of the effect size estimator.

Comment: You say that "M(n)" is the estimator of the mean. Then "M_1(n_1) - M_2(n_2)" (for two different groups) would be the estimator of the mean difference between the two groups. Now just divide this by the estimator of the SD and you have the estimator of the standardized mean difference. It is a (slightly biased) estimator of the parameter $(\mu_1 - \mu_2) / \sigma$.

Comment: Thank you Wolfgang. Do you have a reference for me that addresses this question from a mathematical point of view? Also with the calculation of the variance of this standardized difference estimator? Thank you in advance !

Comment: I would say this is the canonical reference on this topic: Hedges, L. V. (1981). Distribution theory for Glass's estimator of effect size and related estimators. Journal of Educational Statistics, 6(2), 107-128.

Comment: Thank you very much Wolfgang !